# Bind imported function context

Tags: javascript

Considering the following example is there a valid way to bind the function to whatever context it is being executed in?

```
// External.js
function onInput () {
  console.log(data)
}


// Index.js
import { onInput } from 'external.js'

const data = 1
const input = document.querySelector(`input`)
input.addEventListener(`input`, onInput)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript has lexical scope, not dynamic scope. This is not possible.

You could define `data` in a scope that `onInput` can access and provide a way to change the value of `data`, e.g.

```
// External.js
let data;

export function setData(v) {
  data = v;
}

export function onInput () {
  console.log(data)
}

// Index.js
import { onInput, setData } from 'external.js'

setData(1);
const input = document.querySelector(`input`)
input.addEventListener(`input`, onInput)
```

---

Other options:

Make the value an argument of the function. That's probably the more traditional way:

```
// External.js
export function onInput (data) {
  console.log(data)
}

// Index.js
import { onInput } from 'external.js'

const data = 1;
const input = document.querySelector(`input`)
input.addEventListener(`input`, () => onInput(data))
```

Make `data` a property of the function itself:

```
// External.js
export function onInput (data) {
  console.log(onInput.data)
}

// Index.js
import { onInput } from 'external.js'

onInput.data = 1;
const input = document.querySelector(`input`)
input.addEventListener(`input`, onInput)
```

Comment: Shouldn't `changeData` be `onInput` ?

Comment: @DacreDenny: Doesn't really matter how the function is made available. Up to personal preference.

Comment: @FelixKling but `changeData` isn't even defined, so an error will be thrown

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn: I misunderstood the comment. I assume it's a typo in the OP's question. I updated the answer. Although I don't know what the point of the event handler is now `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @DacreDenny: I misunderstood your comment... not sure which function should be which, but that doesn't change the overall approach.

Comment: @FelixKling yeah, I think you inherited a typo from the OP :)